# Renaming multiple variables with characters in a single column in R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
A       B                       C
NP     All M4                   6
NP     All M4                   8
NP     All FBS                  3
NI     C1_D2                    8
NI     C1D9: PT PI-4, A,B AM1   6
NI     C1D9: PT P3,4 B,E A6     9
NN     W1D5: PRE                2
NN     W1D5: PRE                6
NI     W1D5: PRE                5
```

```
A <- c("NP", "NP", "NP", "NI", "NI", "N1", "NN", "NN", "N1")
B <- c("All M4", "All M4", "All FBS", "C1_D2", "C1D9: PT PI-4, A,B AM1", "C1D9: PT P3,4 B,E A6 ", "W1D5: PRE", "W1D5: PRE", "W1D5: PRE")
C <- c("6","8","3","8","6","9","2","6","5")

df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
df
```

And I would like to rename the variables in column B, then group by column A and D to get a sum of column C.  My current code so far is:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
 mutate(D = case_when(
 startsWith(B, "All") ~ "ALL",
 startsWith(B, "C1_D") ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 2",
 startsWith(B, "C1D9") ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 9",
 startsWith(B, "W1D5") ~ "WELL 1 DEAL 5",
)) %>%
group_by(A, D) %>% summaries(C =n())
```

I am getting the error code: problem with mutate() input Visit x Case 3 (startWith(B, "All" ~ "ALL") must be a two-sided formula, not a character vector.
Any other way to write the code more efficiently would be appreciated as I do not have a preferring to using base R.

df2 should look like this

```
A   D                 C
NP  ALL               17
NI  CASE 1 DEAL 2     8
NI  CASE 1 DEAL 9     15
NN  WELL 1 DEAL 5     8
NI  WELL 1 DEAL 5     5
```

Comment: Do you want to change the whole string or just the initial part?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your inquiry.  I have added what df2 output should be.  So basically I don't care if column B gets carried over to df2.  Also they way I wrote my code I am creating a new column D based on column B.  But changing the variables in df column B to ALL, CASE 1 DEAL 2 and so forth would be ok as well.

Comment: See edited solution. Does this help?

Comment: Unlike the answers below, I get your expected output without needing to change `startsWith` to another function, so long as I fix a couple mistakes (change `N1` to `NI`, and change `summaries(C =n())` to `summarise(C =sum(as.integer(N)))`.  However, I'm using R 4.1.1, where the `stringsAsFactors` argument of `data.frame` defaults to `FALSE`.  I suspect that the error you're getting may be due to using an older R version where this argument defaults to `TRUE`.  (You can always explicitly set it to `FALSE`, though.)

Comment: I should add, using one of those other functions suggested in the answers (which I believe deal with strings-as-factors by coercing the data back into a string) instead of using `startsWith` is also a perfectly fine option.  But I wanted to add the above comment just to clarify *why* your original approach didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(D = case_when(grepl("^All", B) ~ "ALL",
                       grepl("^C1_D", B) ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 2",
                       grepl("^C1D9", B) ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 9",
                       grepl("^W1D5", B) ~ "WELL 1 DEAL 5")) %>%
  group_by(A,D) %>%
  summarise(C = sum(as.numeric(C)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   A [4]
  A     D                 C
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 N1    CASE 1 DEAL 9     9
2 N1    WELL 1 DEAL 5     5
3 NI    CASE 1 DEAL 2     8
4 NI    CASE 1 DEAL 9     6
5 NN    WELL 1 DEAL 5     8
6 NP    ALL              17
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `str_detect` from `stringr` package to detect the strings
2. group and `summarise` the `sum` of C

```
df %>% 
    type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(D = case_when(
        str_detect(B, "All") ~ "ALL",
        str_detect(B, "C1_D") ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 2",
        str_detect(B, "C1D9") ~ "CASE 1 DEAL 9",
        str_detect(B, "W1D5") ~ "WELL 1 DEAL 5",
        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
    group_by(D, A) %>% 
    summarise(C = sum(C)) %>% 
    select(A, D, C)
```

```
 A     D                 C
  <chr> <chr>         <int>
1 NP    ALL              17
2 NI    CASE 1 DEAL 2     8
3 N1    CASE 1 DEAL 9     9
4 NI    CASE 1 DEAL 9     6
5 N1    WELL 1 DEAL 5     5
6 NN    WELL 1 DEAL 5     8
```

Comment: approximately same time as your edit. your first try was another one. therefore I will leave! As yours is a good solution I voted up!

Answer (score 0):

We may create a key/value dataset and do a `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

keydat <- tibble(B2 = c("All", "C1_D", "C1D9", "W1D5"),
    D = c("ALL", "CASE 1 DEAL 2", "CASE 1 DEAL 9", "WELL 1 DEAL 5"))
regex_left_join(df, keydat, by = c("B" = "B2")) %>%
      select(-B2) %>%
      group_by(D, A) %>% 
      summarise(C = sum(as.numeric(C)), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  D             A         C
  <chr>         <chr> <dbl>
1 ALL           NP       17
2 CASE 1 DEAL 2 NI        8
3 CASE 1 DEAL 9 N1        9
4 CASE 1 DEAL 9 NI        6
5 WELL 1 DEAL 5 N1        5
6 WELL 1 DEAL 5 NN        8
```